# graphics driver new version not tested

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce, additional-drivers

after updating nvidia driver to version 510, in the additional drivers instead 510 tested it showing 470 tested and it happens after reinstalling ubuntu(21.10). My device with hybrid graphic cards.
Is it an issue with version 510 and with new version it will be fixed?

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTAYl.png)

Comment: Hello. No one can tell you that. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver in the screenshot in the question is nvidia-driver-510, not nvidia-driver-470 (tested). To avoid the uncertainty of deciding between installing tested or not tested drivers you can let Ubuntu install and upgrade the NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers automatically by running the following command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot # first uninstall the existing NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver
```

After you have installed the NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers automatically they may be automatically upgraded to a newer version package(s) by the normal software update process if the newer version packages are compatible with your GPU.